# can't maintain question mark in query string

Tags: php, url, drupal

I'm using drupal's `l()` function to build a link. So I'm passing this variable as a second argument that the function will generate the href value from.

```
$performer = $row->node_field_data_field_evenement_performer_title;
$url = 'node/' . $row->node_field_data_field_evenement_performer_nid . '/lightbox2';
print  l($performer, $url, array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => array('rel' => 'lightframe[group|width:500px; height: 500px][caption]', 'class' => 'performer-link')));
```

The URL should end with the query string `?format=simple`.  So basically my `$url` variable should be updated something like:

```
$url = 'node/' . $row->node_field_data_field_evenement_performer_nid . '/lightbox2?format=simple';
```

No matter what encode/decode function I wrap around, and whatever escaping I do, that question mark and equals sign keep getting interpreted as `%25` types of characters.
I tried:

```
$url = 'node/' . $row->node_field_data_field_evenement_performer_nid . '/lightbox2\?format\=simple');
```

or

```
'/lightbox2' . any_decode_or_encode_function_outthere('?format=simple');
```

but I keep getting URLs like `node/202/lightbox2%5C%3Fformat%5C%3Dsimple`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `query` key for the options array passed to `l()`:

```
print l($performer, $url, array(
  'html' => TRUE,
  'attributes' => array(
    'rel' => 'lightframe[group|width:500px; height: 500px][caption]',
     'class' => 'performer-link'
  ),
  'query' => array(
    'format' => 'simple'
  )
));
```

`l()` calls `url()` internally, and options can be forwarded on. See the docs for [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/6)

Answer (score 0):

Try `l($performer, $url, array('query' => array('format' => 'simple'), /*...the rest of your array...*/ );`

This is for drupal 7. In the options array you can specify a query array which is a key-value array of things to append to the url query string.